# Can PAGELATCH Waits cause increase in SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We have a high concurrency web server application on which we have some amount of PAGELATCH_UP & PAGELATCH_SH Waits due to tempdb contention. But recently we have noticed the SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD Waits also going up. Could the PAGELATCH Waits cause the SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD Wait to go up?

Comment: if you post this on dba.stackexchange.com you'll get some really good answers.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that